# Using Python to count unique list elements of two strings separated by a space

Tags: python, list, ordereddictionary

I have a list of elements of two strings and a space.  I would like to count the unique number of elements and order the list.

```
plist = ('burleson both', 'the largemouth', 'the largemouth', 'a 19inch', 'his first')
```

So would like to get the following:

```
plist = [('the largemouth',2), ('burleson both', 1), ('a 19inch', 1), ('his first', 1)]
```

I've tried the following but it seems to create multiple redundant lists:

```
unique_order_list = {}
for item in plist:
    unique_order_list[item] = plist.count(item)
d = OrderedDict(sorted(unique_order_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: `'the largemouth', 'for largemouth'` - Are they both the same?

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? you say you want to count 'unique number of elements', what does that mean?                      'the largemouth' and 'for largemouth' are not the same and you have them counted as the same, but under 'the largemouth'. We need more context.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. 'the largemouth' element should be in there twice.

Comment: @user2743 You are using the `OrderedDict` but still the `largemouth` thingy and `burleson both` are out of order. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
plist = ('burleson both', 'the largemouth', 'the largemouth', 'a 19inch', 'his first')
plist = [(x, plist.count(x)) for x in set(plist)]
plist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

So, we use `set(plist)` to create a set (this is a list, in which each unique element of plist only appears once. Then we use the `count` function to count the number of occurences of each unique element in the original plist. After that we sort based on the second element (using the lambda function). Reverse is set to True, so that the element with most occurences comes first.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be about what you're looking for:

```
plist = ['burleson both', 'the largemouth', 'the largemouth', 'a 19inch', 'his first']
result = []
def index_finder(string,List):
    answer = 0
    for i in List:
        if i != string:
            answer+=1
        else:
            return answer
def verifier(target,List):
    for i in List:
        if i[0] == target:
            return True
    return False

for each in plist:
    if verifier(each,result):
        result[index_finder(each,plist)]= (each,result[index_finder(each,plist)][1] +1)


    else:
        result.append((each,1))
print result
```

On a side note, tuples are immutable and generally not the best tool for counting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import collections

plist = ('burleson both', 'the largemouth', 'the largemouth', 'a 19inch', 'his first')

counts = collections.Counter(plist)

print counts # Counter({'the largemouth': 2, 'a 19inch': 1, 'burleson both': 1, 'his first': 1})
```